# Join two Tables, ignore records from first table if exists in second

Tags: sql-server, join

How to join to tables, if I prefer to get records only from the second table? If no second exists, take record the of the first table.

```
Table A         Table B         Result
pid,name,type   pid,name,type   pid,name,type
1,Anna,null     1,Anna,100      "1,Anna,100"
2,Bea,null      -               "2,Bea,Null"
3,Caro,null     3,Caro,100      "3,Caro,100"    
                3,Caro,200      "3,Caro,200"
```

Edit: I tried to improve my example table.

Comment: It is in no way clear what you want to know. What are the columns of your A and B? In what sense are records from A being ignored in your example?

Comment: Would you have Caro in table A, no row in tableB?

Comment: Persons are either part of a group or member of a group. They may have multiple memberships in a group. Now, I need a list of all persons associated to a group. But the same person only multiple if the person have multiple memberships.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
   ISNULL(A.column1, B.column1),  --perhaps name
   ISNULL(A.column2, B.column2)  --perhaps id
FROM
   TableA A
   FULL OUTER JOIN
   TableB B ON A.column1 = B.column1  --assume name is matching column
```

Edit, I'm assuming you'd have no row in tableA, and "Dave, 6" in tableB. Otherwise, Cybernate's left join is enough

Comment: Not excatly what i needed, but you put me on the right paths. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Left Join, I assume the column names of TableB are Name and ID respectively.

```
SELECT tableA.Name, tableB.Id
  FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.Name = tableB.Name
```